# Configuring nginx on Google App Engine Flexible Environment with Gunicorn

Tags: nginx, python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm working on a Django app and I was deploying it to App Engine Standard environment until now, but then I started using Google Cloud Vision Python library and due to some restrictions I ad to switch to Flexible Environment.

My code works correctly on my local machine with `python manage.py runserver`, but when I deploy it to App Engine I get the following

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I researched the problem, I found out that I need to change nginx settings  as stated [here](https://blog.percy.io/tuning-nginx-behind-google-cloud-platform-http-s-load-balancer-305982ddb340).

**Nginx Settings to Apply**

```
# Tune nginx keepalives to work with the GCP HTTP(S) Load Balancer:
keepalive_timeout 650;
keepalive_requests 10000;
```

But I was unable to find a way to do this. I'm also new to backend development so I don't have much experience.

Here's my `app.yaml` file

```
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app.wsgi

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static
  - url: .*
    script: app.wsgi.application

builtins:
  - django_wsgi: on
```

I tried setting `entrypoint` to the following but it didn't work.

```
entrypoint: gunicorn --keep-alive 650 -b :$PORT app.wsgi
```

**EDIT 1:** This error only occurs with `POST` requests.

**EDIT 2:**
Here's the error log with `http` request:

```
{
 insertId: "1c0for6fm6z812"   
 jsonPayload: {
  trace: "$traceId"    
  latencySeconds: "30.529"    
  time: null    
 }
 httpRequest: {
  requestMethod: "POST"    
  requestUrl: "/users/register/"    
  status: 502    
  responseSize: "568"    
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"    
  remoteIp: "130.211.3.116"    
  referer: "-"    
 }
 resource: {
  type: "gae_app"    
  labels: {
   project_id: "cuz-api"     
   version_id: "20170504t110352"     
   module_id: "default"     
  }
 }
 timestamp: "2017-05-04T08:30:14.560885079Z"   
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: "68f73c569efa"    
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: "8300604998554181598"    
  compute.googleapis.com/zone: "us-central1-b"    
  appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id: "7835424c5d67f87f56649adf26e71250"    
 }
 logName: "projects/cuz-api/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request"   
}
```

And this is the error log with `https` request:

```
{
 insertId: "95tl7qfm6m4zy"   
 jsonPayload: {
  time: null    
  trace: "$traceId"    
  latencySeconds: "30.028"    
 }
 httpRequest: {
  requestMethod: "POST"    
  requestUrl: "/users/register/"    
  status: 502    
  responseSize: "568"    
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"    
  remoteIp: "130.211.3.237"    
  referer: "-"    
 }
 resource: {
  type: "gae_app"    
  labels: {
   version_id: "20170504t110352"     
   module_id: "default"     
   project_id: "cuz-api"     
  }
 }
 timestamp: "2017-05-04T08:26:38.540802339Z"   
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/zone: "us-central1-b"    
  appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id: "3eab23e9502e250d9f00dd5bc7eb465e"    
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: "68f73c569efa"    
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: "8300604998554181598"    
 }
 logName: "projects/cuz-api/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request"   
}
```

Comment: Does the entrypoint command work to run your app if given `PORT=8080` in your dev environment?

Comment: I'm using `manage.py runserver` in my local development environment. The error occurs only with the `POST` requests. Apparently I forgot to mention that, I apologize. I'm editing my question to reflect that information.

Comment: Well at this point the natural question to ask, and the natural test to perform, is: "what happens when you run `gunicorn --keep-alive 650 -b :$PORT app.wsgi`?"

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: When running that command in dev, you send a POST request and get the exact 502 html payload shown in your question? And this is no differnt from when you run it using "manage.py"?

Comment: The 502 error happens when I deploy the project to the Flex environment. I can run and send POST request without any problems on my local machine.

Comment: You had said that running gunicorn in dev produces the same error. Do you not see the error in dev?

Comment: Have you inspected all logs to ensure that there's no information on the error there?

Comment: Finally, can you try to build and run the docker image on your local machine, to see if the issue is really in production or simply the image itself?

Comment: I'm sorry, I said runnging `python manage.py runserver` doesn't give me the same error on my local machine. But I get the same error If I run the `gunicorn` command on my local machine. I checked the logs and the problem got me to [this solution](https://blog.percy.io/tuning-nginx-behind-google-cloud-platform-http-s-load-balancer-305982ddb340) (As mentioned in my question). I just don't know how to apply that solution.

Comment: The only connection between the issue shown in your question and the linked page is that the status code is 502. Did you explicitly see the further detail (from the linked page) of "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client"?

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. I added the error logs I got from GAE to my question. I also tried running `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080 cuz.wsgi` on a macOS, and I did **NOT** get the same error. It worked the way it's supposed to.

Comment: It's not clear then that what you're seeing is actually related to the link in question then. At any rate the 502's only occur in production. There are other places you can check for logs, such as by SSH'ing into the actual instance itself, and once in there, you can also check inside the container running the app or the container running nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no actual need for you to be touching Nginx. The link you are basing yourself on has to do with the HTTP Load Balancer, not with App Engine Flexible.

An example of working Django application on App Engine flexible may be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your app does not run well on the local test machine. When it does, it will become easy to migrate it from a standard environment app to flex by following the "Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment" on-line [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to fix this by increasing the [`timeout`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) setting (defaults to 30 seconds).